# Reliably copy files from one server to another using c#

Tags: c#

I am looking for a programmatic way to copy files from one network drive to another. I have created a program that does a simple copy but this is not enough as the line is not reliable and the files ends up being corrupted. Is there a technology that syncs the folders and does a sum-check or something like that.

I need it to be a c# app as I need to know when the copy is completed so I can process the files on the other side. I am using windows services to co-ordinate this.

I'm just looking for someone to point me in the right direction with tutorials if necessary.

Comment: A few years old but might be useful http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2010/05/10/how-to-copy-very-large-files-across-a-slow-or-unreliable-network.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is [Robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) (aka Robust Copy), it is built in to windows Vista and newer and it has features to retry on network failure.

One down side is there is no "Verify" functionality built in, but if you need to you can use a 3rd party file hashing program and put the copy in a script that verifies the hashes after the copy completes.

Here is a query that copies all files and sub-folders in a restartable mode, if a copy fails it will re-try 1,000,000 times by default waiting 30 seconds between tries. (you can change that with `/r:<N>` and `/w:<N>` where `<N>` is a number)

```
robocopy C:\SourceFolder \\DestComputer\DestFolder /zb /e
```

Answer (score -1):

The only time I have ever done anything like this has been during the deploy process to distributed servers. In that instance I zipped the files, moved and unzipped them using PSEXEC.

If I were you, I would begin by figuring out how to zip the files (To prevent the corruption issues you have described) and then worry about how to move them.